# Downvote vs vote to close question

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, downvotes

I just hit 3,000 reputation and I'm lost as to casting downvotes versus voting to close a question.

- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-down says downvotes are for questions that are *"egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended"*.
- https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions says close votes are for questions that are *"unclear, too broad, or otherwise problematic to identifying the problem"*.

Are these not quite similar? Both seem to describe "bad" questions and I can't quite see when one option should be preferred to the other.

Comment: When close-voting, I usually downvote, too. But not all questions I downvote need to be close-voted.

Comment: Vote to close questions that don't belong on the site. Downvote questions when you feel reading them was a waste of your time. It's common you'll need to do both, but it's not rare to either only close vote or only downvote.

Comment: Feel free to drop in the [SO Close Vote reviewers chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) if you need advice. And you're invited to join our review events where we try to clear some of the close vote queue....

Comment: @Yannis I can think of plenty of situations where a question would merit downvoting but not closing... I can't think of any situations where a question would merit closing but not downvoting, though. What sort of situation are you imagining?

Comment: @neminem Sometimes, a good question is posted on a wrong site. Then there are duplicates

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot about duplicates. Yep, that's a good reason to vote to close without downvoting.

Comment: A well written and clear question my need closing when it is discovered that the problem is a  a simple typographical error.    These questions should not be down voted.

Comment: I would like to suggest combining these two options. If a question gets alot of downvotes, close it.

Comment: @JackOJack Well, what close reason would you select? A custom one, saying "Got a lot of downvotes"?

Comment: @MathiasMüller "Question does not meet community standards as decided by users" would do

Answer (score 37, accepted):

First, downvoting and voting to close aren't mutually exclusive options.  The downvote tool tip says

> This question does not show any research effort; it is unclear or not
>   useful.

"Unclear what you are asking" is a close reason.  For me, when something is so confusing it warrants closing, it also deserves a downvote.  However, something that may be slightly confusing (and usually coupled with other problems) will get a downvote, but may not be egregious enough to be closed.

Sometimes a well researched question may just not belong here.  People come here asking for recommendations for software libraries all the time.  They may have even done research and narrowed it down and just want a random internet stranger's opinion to justify their choice.  Software recommendations are clearly off-topic and should be closed.  Whether it has earned a downvote is up to you.

The short version is this: downvotes are for the bad questions.  Closing is for things that don't belong here.  Many times a question is both, but not always.

Answer (score 8):

"Both seem to describe "bad" questions"

Yes, but they describe two different categories of bad questions. **Some** questions fall into both categories, but it is important to understand the distinction between the categories. Many questions fall into only one category.  As an example, let's cover those which aren't "egregiously sloppy, no-effort-expended" but are "too broad".

#### Questions which are broad or unclear, deserving comments+close votes, but might not be "bad" in terms of lacking effort:

Such a question may be well thought out and defined with lots of background info, but it may in essence cover many distinct scenarios because it is too broad, or is asking several different questions.  Thus it makes them difficult to answer, and/or results in answer having to address a broad range of scenarios(or all possible permutations of scenarios) in order to address the question in its entirety.  Such a question probably needs to be more narrowly defined to address a more limited scenario, and save other scenarios for other questions.

Even if someone were willing to provide a thorough answer that addresses the many different questions/scenarios, it doesn't serve as a good resource.  Others coming along have to sift through the answer to determine what applies to their very narrow scenario.

For that reason it is best to close these questions and suggest to the OP that they be refined/narrowed/split.

As an aside, IMO the broad close reason is sometimes misused by those who simply are not fluent in the technical context of the question.  It can sometimes be misused as a catch-all for "I don't understand what is being asked" which sometimes is simply because the voter doesn't have the technical knowledge surrounding the question's topic.  Sometimes questions asking about a very narrowly defined specific issue, but involve a somewhat odd scenario get close votes for this.  Or if people don't read the question carefully, or feel the question's premise is invalid.  I asked a question about `Url.Action` one time but readers somehow misread this as the more common method `Html.Action` and thus were confused by the question because the question would make no sense in the context of `Html.Action`.

Moral of the story is its best to carefully read the question a couple times and IMO vote only if it covers subject matter you are well versed in.

Answer (score 4):

In my opinion, the answers given so far are not satisfying, so I'll add another one.

Yes, both voting to close and downvotes are ways to deal with "bad" questions, and, as I see it, there is an intersection of questions where both should be applied.

**Questions that deserve to be downvoted only**

You should downvote questions that

- do not show any research effort, where a trivial Google query would likely have solved the problem
- are written in a careless and sloppy manner, so one has to assume that the OP does not care about getting good answers very much
- are not helpful in the sense that an answer to them is unlikely to help any other user (a remnant of the "too localized" close reason) - a good question puts the problem in a wider context

**Questions that deserve to be closed only**

You should vote to close questions that

- are exact duplicates of other questions
- belong to another site of the StackExchange network (migration)
- ask for recommendations
- are too broad and would require a whole documentation to be reproduced as an answer
- are based on opinions instead of hard facts

**Questions that deserve to be both downvoted and closed**

You should vote to close and downvote questions that

- are spam, or contain links to porn sites, or are completely unintelligible gibberish
- are very impolite and aggressive
- are written in a language other than English
- are unclear, because a) there is no real question or because b) relevant code is not included

From my point of view, downvoting tends to be for questions that *should not be answered*, whereas voting to close tends to be for questions that *cannot be answered* (either because of the sheer impossibility or the policy of Stackoverflow).

But of course, millions of questions can hardly be crammed into a handful of categories and there will always be intermediate categories and opinions differ on some. For example,

- if a question lacks effort and solutions are easily found, there should be an early SO post already that is a duplicate
- non-English questions are often translated by other users
- opinion-based questions *might* be a good fit for the Programmers site

And then there's always the option to opt out of doing anything because you're too far from your field of expertise and are skating on thin ice.

Comment: "are not helpful in the sense that an answer to them is unlikely to help any other user"  I don't think this is reason enough to down-vote. It is perfectly fine to ask about your own specific, technical problem. I up-vote questions that _are_ helpful to others, than down-voting those that are not.

Comment: @Lundin Then how do you explain "Too localized" ever existed as a close reason? But perhaps my wording is "not helpful": I meant _framing_ your problem in a way that allows others with similar problems to make use of the answer.

Comment: It doesn't exist as a close reason any longer. I'm certain there's some debate on meta about why it was removed.

Comment: @Lundin How should I edit my answer in your opinion, to make it more accurate?

Comment: I'd just remote that whole sentence, but that's my personal opinion.

Comment: @Lundin I'm inclined to do that, one last question: How do you interpret "not useful" in the tooltip of the downvote button?

Comment: It doesn't add anything of value to anyone. There's a big difference between "here is my very specifical technical problem" and "give me code". Just use common sense when closing as well as when down voting.

Comment: @Lundin I'm not convinced. To me, "unlikely to help other users" is the same as "doesn't add anything of value to anyone". But let's not argue any further - we both know the system well.