# Improve How to Tag Instructions

Tags: feature-request, tags

Users do not appreciate how tags are implemented. The issue has been highlighted many times, [specifically for Python](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288855/adding-python-tag-to-non-version-specific-python-questions-is-it-acceptable) too.

Probably *not* coincidentally, the image shows the single post tagged `[python]` with 3x more views at an early stage.

[image]

**What this means**

- Many questions don't get the exposure they deserve, as users may not favourite version tags.
- Many questions can't be closed correctly as duplicates, as there are very few version-specific gold badge holders.
- The search function does not work as well as it should.

**Statistics**

For [those who think](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365548/improve-how-to-tag-instructions#comment570933_365548) visibility is not a problem, followers by tag:-

- `[python]`: 552k followers
- `[python 3.x]`:  76k followers
- `[python 2.7]`:  42k followers
- `[python 2.x]`:  239 followers

Some front-page statistics (top 30 on `[python-3.x]` page) to support these numbers:

```
                        Count    Total views    Avg views    Median views
python-3.x + python        13            307        23.62              22
python-3.x only            17            186        10.94               9
```

**Solutions**

1. <s>Implement related tags.</s> This has been asked for already.
2. <s>Force questioners to use a non version-specific tag.</s> This has been asked for already.
3. Improve the "How to Tag" description to be **more succinct** and **explicitly state** that *non-version tags should always be included*.

The 3rd solution is straightforward and easy to implement.

**Suggestions**

In the greyed out text box:-

From:

> "at least one tag (such as .., ..., ....)"

To:

> "at least one non version-specific tag (such as.., ...,  ...)"

In the bullet points, put in the second bullet:-

> - use a tag for your category which is not version specific.

Comment: related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/365538/7311767 ?

Comment: A tag that is favorited by 75,500 users and 95,000 questions does not have an exposure problem.  There is something going on between you and another hi-rep [python] contributor, having that spill over into meta like this is not productive.  Learn to live with each other, be tolerant.

Comment: @HansPassant. Interesting comment. Would you care to address the solution proposed in this question?

Comment: Do you really think that these new users are actually reading those tag instructions?  That said, how do you think the description should be changed?  What are you suggesting it say?

Comment: @Servy, if that's the case, then remove the tag instructions? I've added some trivial suggestions. If I was a new user, the additional advice would *absolutely not* be obvious to me if it wasn't explicit.

Comment: `1` They deserve it, `2` Just downvote, `3` Use Google. (although (3) seems NAA... anyway SO search system is definitely worse than Google)

Comment: @user202729, see [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284571/9209546): "The short version is this: downvotes are for the bad questions. Closing is for things that don't belong here. Many times a question is both, but not always." A duplicate may be well researched, but may be an instance of the *same problem being approached with 2 different terminologies* - users should not be penalized for this. Duplicates *should be encouraged* if they indicate different wording / terminology / frameworks which happen to have a common solution.

Comment: Are mistagging bad? "are written in a careless and sloppy manner" / Of course you can retract the downvote after the issue has been fixed.

Comment: @user202729, the point is, how is a *new user meant to know*? Check out which tags are popular / read up individual tag descriptions for usage? What I am suggesting is a far more direct approach.

Comment: ... Good point, upvote.

Comment: But hopefully at least 1% of the current mis-taggers will read them.

Comment: Although... there are both {questions that have python-3.x but not python} and {questions that have python but not python-3.x}. The latter case is also a problem.

Comment: @user202729, yeh that's why I linked to the other meta. It's the first case that's causing issues.

Comment: Is this the consensus on how tagging should happen? I seem to remember reading something contrary to that but since I can't find it now I can't see whether that was something that had general support.

Comment: @BSMP. For consensus see [1](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288855/adding-python-tag-to-non-version-specific-python-questions-is-it-acceptable), [2](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364213/version-specific-tags-hide-questions-from-users-subscribed-to-version-agnostic-t), [3](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265844/should-i-not-use-the-generic-tag-if-my-solution-is-limited-to-a-specific-version), [4](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333015/how-to-encourage-users-to-tag-with-non-versioned-tags). Seems pretty conclusive.