# Voting on a suggested edit that is later "improved" by adding a tag breaks the dupehammer

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, suggested-edits, dupehammer

It seems like accepting or rejecting a suggested edit **that makes no changes to the question's tags** can still prevent your dupehammer from taking effect if the edit is later "improved" by another user and the "improved" edit adds the relevant tag.

I noticed this when I tried to hammer [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50229813/python3-accessing-class-attributes-in-a-generator-at-initialisaton). The timeline is as follows:

1. A question with a `python-3.x` tag but no `python` tag is posted.
2. A low-rep user suggests an edit. The suggested edit does **not** add the `python` tag.
3. I reject the suggested edit. (Presumably the same thing would've happened if I had accepted the edit.)
4. Another user reviews the suggested edit and improves it by adding a `python` tag.
5. As a consequence of a high-rep user improving the suggested edit, the system automatically approves the suggested edit.
6. I try to hammer the question (I have `python` gold, but no `python-3.x` gold), but the system thinks I "participated in editing the question's tags" and thus the hammer doesn't work.

Most of this can be seen in the question's [revisions](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50229813/revisions) and [timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/50229813/timeline).

Can we have this fixed or should I just refrain from reviewing edits if I'm planning to hammer the question?

Comment: If you refrain from reviewing the edit and the flow becomes like this > _suggested edit > hammer > edit approved_ doesn't the question automaticly go to the reopen queue?

Comment: @AndréKool I don't know, but I think in this context the question is moot - I *can't* hammer the question until the edit is approved or rejected and someone adds a `python` tag.

Comment: I think you'll have to refrain from reviewing edits. The rules are very restrictive. I don't think there are plans to change them. There needs to be additional logic in the system, i.e. force a version-specific tag to be accompanied by a generic tag. But the idea's been rejected many times in multiple ways.

Comment: No offence but how can you plan on hammering a question without the tag you have a gold badge in?

Comment: @AndréKool I wait for someone to add the tag. The question was tagged `python-3.x`; it's undoubtedly a python question and thus I'm qualified to hammer it once someone adds the relevant tag. If only OPs would read the tagging guidelines or SO would implement tag hierarchies, we wouldn't have this problem... :(

Comment: If only we had a single tag for all python questions, so we woundn't have to worry about askers only using the versioned tags...

Comment: If only we had [clearer instructions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/365548/improve-how-to-tag-instructions).

Comment: @Braiam If only the makers of Python didn't make their major versions incompatible with each other

Comment: I agree, this seems like a bug; you played no part in getting the [tag:python] tag added to the question, so you should be able to dupehammer it.

Comment: Given everything else going on, this edge case is probably pretty low on the totem pole. I would suggest refraining from reviewing the edit if you plan on hammering

Comment: @TylerH The same happens for java and for every language with versions though.

Comment: @Sulthan I don't frequent the Java tag but I would presume then that there are version-specific Java tags if that's the case. If version 3 is *incompatible* with version 2, then readers need to know you are using version 2 or version 3.

Comment: @AndréKool No (re your first comment), edits from those that have voted to close or flagged the question do not put the question in the reopen queue. See: [Lots of questions in the reopen queue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/196078)

Answer (score 7):

As I see it, this is two bugs:

1. You didn't vote to approve the suggested edit, so your hands should've been clean even if it *had* added the tag. But the logic doesn't differentiate between approval and rejection when deciding who to disallow for badge-hammer privileges.
2. You had nothing to do with the revision (Improve-ment) that actually did add the tag. But the system is apparently identifying the wrong revision as the one that added the tag.

Fixing either one of these would've avoided trouble in your exact situation. Fixing both - looking only at approvals *and* at the correct revision in cases of improvement - should avoid a more substantial body of problems.